# How to keep ADA in Yoroi wallet without staking?

Tags: stake-pool

Hi I send some ADA to my Yoroi wallet but it staked into the pool automatically, I want to keep some ADA in the wallet so I can claim coins from Drip Drops, how do I  do it?

Answer (score 1):

On Cardano, you are staking with your wallet. It locks a 2ADA deposit that you will get back when you unstake.

So you are free to claim your tokens from Drip Dropz or spend the ADA even when you are staking.

Answer (score 0):

Staking on Cardano is non-custodial and you can use the staked Ada anytime.

Once you register you wallet to stake to a stake pool, all future Ada added to the wallet is automatically staked to the same pool.

The 2 Ada staking deposit is refunded when you choose to de-register from the stake pool and stop staking.

- You can claim the staking rewards without de-registering
- You can switch pools without de-registering

These will cost a transaction fee (~0.17ada at this time)

- Registering with a stake pool (2 Ada refundable)
- De-registering
- Changing stake pool
- Claiming stake rewards

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to stake your ada from yoroi, there is an option in the main area "withdraw".

when you click there, there is another question you received -either to keep registered - or to deregister.

Deregistering means this key will no longer receive rewards until you re-register the staking key (usually by delegating to a pool again).

but we will recommend you to have a small research what exactly CArdano is, Proof of Stake, and why this "stake" help the network, ADA and more specific your asset.

if you have any further questions, please never hesitate to contact us.

Cardano is a great huge Community, and we are all happy to assist.

have a nice Sun-day.

pool operator for TTS17

theTokenSquare17

PS.
based on my understanding and research, i can see only a reason someone who doesnt want to Stake, only in case of Taxes, and this "income" he receives (rewards).